# Visual Studio 2010 Configuration to run PCL Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, point-cloud-library

I have a problem when trying to debug a simple PCL (Point-Cloud-Library Application) application in MS Visual C++ 2010 that has to visualize a point cloud. (This example: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php)

I setup the C++ project with all the include and library folders needed for PCL. 
I add to the linker input the following dependencies:

```
openNI.lib 
libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib 
libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib 
libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib 
libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib 
libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib 
pcl_common_debug.lib pcl_apps_debug.lib 
pcl_features_debug.lib 
pcl_filters_debug.lib 
pcl_io_debug.lib 
pcl_io_ply_debug.lib 
pcl_kdtree_debug.lib 
pcl_keypoints_debug.lib 
pcl_octree_debug.lib 
pcl_registration_debug.lib 
pcl_sample_consensus_debug.lib 
pcl_search_debug.lib 
pcl_segmentation_debug.lib 
pcl_surface_debug.lib 
pcl_tracking_debug.lib 
pcl_visualization_debug.lib 
vtkRendering-gd.lib 
QVTK-gd.lib 
vtkalglib-gd.lib 
vtkCharts-gd.lib 
vtkCommon-gd.lib 
vtkDICOMParser-gd.lib 
vtkexoIIc-gd.lib 
vtkexpat-gd.lib 
vtkFiltering-gd.lib 
vtkfreetype-gd.lib 
vtkftgl-gd.lib 
vtkGenericFiltering-gd.lib 
vtkGeovis-gd.lib 
vtkGraphics-gd.lib 
vtkhdf5-gd.lib 
vtkHybrid-gd.lib 
vtkImaging-gd.lib 
vtkInfovis-gd.lib 
vtkIO-gd.lib 
vtkjpeg-gd.lib 
vtklibxml2-gd.lib 
vtkmetaio-gd.lib 
vtkNetCDF_cxx-gd.lib 
vtkNetCDF-gd.lib 
vtkpng-gd.lib 
vtkproj4-gd.lib 
vtksqlite-gd.lib 
vtksys-gd.lib 
vtktiff-gd.lib 
vtkverdict-gd.lib 
vtkViews-gd.lib 
vtkVolumeRendering-gd.lib 
vtkWidgets-gd.lib 
vtkzlib-gd.lib 
OpenGL32.Lib
```

When i start debugging the IDE ends up with the following link error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib'

The library "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib" is not contained in the set of boost library of the 3party folder of PCL. What am I doing wrong? Is there another path for VS2010 configuration for PCL programs?

Additional information:
I downloaded last version 1.6 of PCL, choosing the MSVC2010 version all-in-one.
I set up the code generation with /MTd (Multi-threaded debug)
I'm running the project with debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

You already got libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib so enable your project to use dynamic linking in "configuration properties". 
Another option is to download Boost and build it using static linking to generate the libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib file. Don't forget to set the folder of "Linker" -> "Additional Library directories" to the location of the file.